# How to make a scrollable view that automatically scrolls to fixed positions

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing a resource for Machinists to use on their phone. It has lots of shop information in it. And I would like to include a calculator that can do a little bit of trig.

I am creating a button layout with all of the input keys, instead of using the android keyboard. I want to have two layouts side by side. The user will be able to scroll horizontally to get to one from the other.

Algeo, a great scientific calculator on Android, has an example of this. Algeo's keyboard is 3 different sets of buttons. And you can scroll horizontally between them. If you scroll halfway through two button layouts, it will automatically scroll it so one is centered. It will not let you scroll so you have 1/3rd of one layout, and 2/3rd's of another, or any other way you could split them.

I would like to know how to replicate this. I assume I need to use a container other than HorizontalScrollView, but, I'm unsure of what container it would be.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`ViewPager`‍](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Horizontal Scrolling that Snaps to List Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840405/android-horizontal-scrolling-that-snaps-to-list-items)